# What does "report" mean and why is it not in the past simple form?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, tense

In the quote, does "report" mean "[if you report something that has happened, you **tell** people about it](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/report)"? If it means "tell", why doesn't the quote use the past simple "reported", while "said" is in the past simple form?

> Less than half of men **report** being satisfied with their friendships,
> and only about 1 in 5 **said** they had received emotional support from a
> friend in the last week ... ([BBC](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/11/29/health/men-friendships-wellness/index.html))

Comment: It does appear inconsistent on its face. Maybe scholars can justify it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Does it simply mean "tell"?

Comment: *Report* means a bit more than *tell*. It's like *repeat an inner story* or *admit a secret*.

Comment: Or _tell the researchers_.

Comment: It's the simple present tense.  We often use this tense in English to talk of something that is a general fact, or which has been discovered from research.  It's common.  E.g..  Research shows that most people are in fact quite nice!  Most Christians say that they believe in Jesus.

Comment: Can I use the verb "report" when those surveyed are not saying anything? They do the survey by ticking the response options on paper.

Comment: Yes, I think you could use _report_ even when their feedback was ticking boxes. I think it's a journalistic word in this meaning: I wouldn't use it in ordinary speech to refer to the results of a survey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reporting on a survey like this, it is common to use present or past tense; but in this case, the writer seems to have changed their mind half way through.

I don't think I would have noticed the change if I had been reading the report; but it is inconsistent, as you suggest.